# What does this snippet do in perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

What does the following do in `Perl`?

```
$string =~ s#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+# #sg;  
$string =~ s#\s+# #sg;
```

I undestand that `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` is a start of sentence and at least one of `a-zA-Z0-9` and `\s+` is at least one whitespace.
But I can not figure out what this snippet does as a whole.

Comment: Why don't you take it for a spin? it's simple enough code. feed in some strings and see what comes out.

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is not the start of the sentence. `^` has different meanings in `^...` and `[^...]`.

Comment: Also, I think the first regex already includes the second regex for non-Unicode `$string`

Comment: yes, it does; the second substitution never does anything (well, except replace a single space by a single space as many times as needed)

Answer (score 4):

First, it replaces any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters (being neither upper case chars, lower case chars nor numbers) in the string with a single space.

After that it replaces all multi-spaces, i.e. any sequence of whitespaces with just one space character.

Comment: Not in a line. The `/s` flag does the substitution for every line at once. And more, the character class (`[...]`) matches newline, so they will be removed too.

Comment: right. It was a left over from my mis-interpretation of the caret - I first read it to be right after the `#` meaning at he beginning of it all. Then I realized that it's inside the group.
I edited the answer. Thx

Comment: Here is more languages than english... ;), so `alphanumeric` is misleading a bit - only for `ascii`, not for `Ángry bird` :)

Comment: @Birei: The `/s` modifier affects only the `.` metacharacter, which it changes to make it match any character instead of anything but a newline. In this case there are none in the pattern so it has no effect at all.

Comment: @Borodin: You are right. My brain assumes that when finds the `/s` flag but it's not accurate.

Answer (score 3):

the first pattern replace all that is not alphanumeric by a space.

The second replace any number of white characters (space, tab, newlines) by a single space

Note that you can replace these two patterns by an only pattern:

```
$string =~ s#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+# #sg;
```

Comment: No. I think it's not correct join all it in the same pattern, because `\S` adds puntuactions and other symbols inside the character class, that would be excluded.

Comment: @Birei: you are right, a simple negation of alnum contains white characters.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte:Sorry for the lamen question. 1)Isn't `#` a comment in perl? How can this code work? 2) How is the replacement by space is done. I.e. which part of the code replaces alnum by space

Comment: s, m, tr, y, q, qq, qr, qx, qw all work with arbitrary delimiters; here s uses # as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string =~ s#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+# #sg;  
$string =~ s#\s+# #sg;
```

is more commonly written as

```
$string =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/ /sg;  
$string =~ s/\s+/ /sg;
```

The choice of delimiter isn't significant, but `/` is used by convention unless the pattern contains many some `/`.

Here we have two instances of the substitution operator. Between the first two delimiters is a regular expression pattern to search for. Between the last two delimiters is the string with which to replace the matching text. The trailing `s` and `g` are flags.

The `s` flag affects what `.` matches. Given that `.` isn't used, the `s` flag is useless.

The `g` flag causes the all matches to be replaced instead of just the first one.

---

**The first regex pattern, `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`**

`[...]` is a character class that matches a single character among those specified. A leading `^` negates the class, so `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any character other than unaccented latin letters and numbers.

`atom+` matches `atom` one or more times, so `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches a sequence of non-alphanumeric characters (and some alphanumeric characters such as "é").

Therefore, `s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/ /g` replaces all sequences of non-alphanumeric characters (and some alphanumeric characters such as "é") with a single space. For example, `"abc - déf :)"` becomes `"abc d f "`.

---

**The second regex pattern, `\s+`**

`\s` matches any whitespace character (except the vertical tab and the non-breaking space sometimes).

Therefore, `s/\s+/ /g` replaces all sequences of white space with a single space. For example, `"abc\tdef   ghi\n"` becomes `"abc def ghi "`.

---

**As a whole**

When used together, the second statement does absolutely nothing. There will never be any sequences of two or more whitespace characters left in `$string` after the first statement.

So

```
$string =~ s#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+# #sg;  
$string =~ s#\s+# #sg;
```

is the same as

```
$string =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/ /g;
```